# Translating Unicode Values

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

This is a strange question but some time ago, and I don't know where I found this, I was able to add a line in Python using the following code:

```
unicode("\xc4", "cp437")
```

And I don't know how I got to that.  I know it's decoding that as a code page 437 and that \xc4 is a line but can find no reference to that - I only know what the output is.

Now I want to do the same thing but with a star symbol.  The symbol, according to https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/ is:

```
 U+0272A (unicode)
 &#x272A; (hex)
 &#10026; (html)
```

How do I convert one or more of those values into a similar command to get the star symbol that I'm after?

Essentially this is a Python program that interfaces with a Mac software program and I don't know how they interpret all of this once they read and execute the Python script but, as I said, I know the example I posted allows that software to add a solid line to the user interface.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `'\u272a'` (Python 3) or `u'\u272a'` (Python 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Python 2**

You can use the Unicode string literal `u'\u272a'`:

```
>>> print u'\u272a'
✪
```

Not sure how you came to use code page 437 for your other symbol (`Box Drawings Light Horizontal`), but when you can get the Unicode code for that symbol by evaluating what you had (Python 2):

```
>>> unicode("\xc4", "cp437")
u'\u2500'
>>> print u'\u2500'
─
```

**Python 3**

You can use the string literal `'\u272a'`:

```
>>> print('\u272a')
✪
```

Comment: Thanks for that, although that symbol doesn't look like the star it supposed to look like it gives me some great info.  How do you incorporate that into a string variable?  Would it be s = u'\2500'?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to encode the CIRCLED WHITE STAR symbol U+272A using cp437 encoding:

```
>>> u'\u272a'.encode('cp437')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u272a' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

This value cannot be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

Comment: I understand that the star is not part of cp437, but is it a part of another usable code set that I am able to use?

Comment: The star symbol doesn't exist in cp437 as you pointed out, and I was aware of that already.  The unicode symbol for a star that I posted is what I would like to use but I'm not sure what CP that comes from so I was hoping that someone could clarify which CP needs to be referenced in order to get to that symbol.

Comment: Nowadays, one use utf-8 encoding to encode Unicode strings. You can also use utf-16 and utf-32. There are others…